# Is it possible to “ping” an embedded device connected through a JTAG interface (USB)?

Tags: windows, usb, ip, ping, embedded

I currently have an atmel at91sam7x256 embedded device that is connected to my Windows machine through a JTAG interface of USB type. I am having difficulties getting the ethernet port to work, and therefore cannot obtain the board's IP address.

Therefore, I'm wondering if it is possible to ping an embedded device whilst it's connected through a USB cable on a Windows machine. If so, how do I do so? I know I can simply ping the device if I had its IP address but sadly this isn't a possibilty for me.

**UPDATE**

I found [a site](https://github.com/mindboards/ev3dev/wiki/Setting-Up-Windows-USB-Ethernet-Networking) that would allow me to treat a USB port as an Ethernet device. The concept is called "Ethernet over USB". So, I go to "device manager" and my device is a J-Link JTAG interface, located in "Universal serial bus controllers". I keep following their instructions in order to assign the port an IP address. But, at the step of choosing "Microsft Corporation -> Remote NDIS Compatible device", I don't have that option. This is what I have: [image].

Is there a way, given these options, in which I can continue the same tutorial to add an IP address?

Comment: Since USB does not support TCP/IP naturally, you cannot just ping it, but I found this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_USB It looks like it's possible to make Windows believe the USB connection is an ethernet one, and then assign an IP address.

Comment: @daraos Thank you for your answer. This article explains the Ethernet over USB concept pretty well. How do I implement the idea however? I.e, assigning an IP address? Do you happen to have any links to that?

Comment: I found this: http://www.bahia21.com/download.htm that tells me to download the device driver, but I'm not sure if it's the right one. And, I'm not sure what to do next. I would appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm sorry Adam, I have not needed this myself before, so I cannot share experience on it.

Comment: @daraos Just a side note. The ICMP ECHO request (often referred to as *ping*) does not rely on TCP/IP.

Comment: You are of course right Oliver, I'm forgetting the basics!

Comment: Please take a look at the update.